# Youtube comment use selenium

Tags: xpath

```
import subprocess
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

subprocess.Popen(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="C:\chrometemp"') # 디버거 크롬 구동

option = Options()
option.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options = option)
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_XulUbBra5M'
driver.get(url)

driver.maximize_window() # 크롬 창 크기 최대화
driver.implicitly_wait(3) # 페이지 로드까지 3초간 기다림

heihgt = driver.execute_script(
    "return document.documentElement.scrollHeight"
)
# 기존 위치
stand_height = 0

while True:
    # 현재 높이
    current_height = driver.execute_script(
        "return document.documentElement.scrollHeight"
    )

    driver.execute_script(
        f"window.scrollTo(0, {stand_height});"  #스크롤 내리기
    )
    time.sleep(1)


    # 스크롤 내린 페이지의 높이
    new_page_height = driver.execute_script(
        "return document.documentElement.scrollHeight"
    )
    stand_height = heihgt

    heihgt = new_page_height
    time.sleep(1)

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='contenteditable-root']")

#driver.close()
```

I'm making a program that uses crawling to comment comments, but when I find the location of comments with xpath, I get the following error: I don't know why.

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='contenteditable-root']"}
(Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.110)

Python does not support driver.find_element_by_xpath , it supports driver.find(By.XPATH,) . Does this cause an error? please tell me why

Comment: Can you share the youtube page you are working on and more your code?

Comment: @Prophet       I upload full code. Please help me.

Comment: I don't see any element matching `//*[@id='contenteditable-root']` there...

Comment: Are you trying to write a new comment or to read the existing comments?

Comment: @Prophet       Tring to wirte a new comment

Answer (score 0):

The input element to insert a new comment is not initially loaded on the page.
To make this element loaded you need to scroll the page down.
Also, to make the actual input comment element to be interactable you first need to click another element.
This should work:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_XulUbBra5M'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.ytp-play-button")))
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='simplebox-placeholder']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='contenteditable-root']"))).send_keys(your_comment_text)
```